# Web application interacts bi-directional with server program?

Tags: php, ajax, linux, command-line, bidirectional

I want to write a web application to play chess against the engine Crafty. I'm not new to PHP and javascript, but must learn how to interact with a server process : how can a web application and/or (jQuery) ajax interact bi-directionally with a (linux) program running on the server?

At this moment i am developing on (Apache) local host. Crafty is installed on my Ubuntu PC. This well-known chess engine has no GUI, it runs in terminal by the command

> $ /usr/games/crafty

and so you can play chess against it and even see it's calculations :

[image: crafty in terminal]

I can make Crafty run by PHP, using the functions proc_open() or exec(), and most documentation i found states that the output stream should be a file .. But i think i don't want such setup, because then the webpage should be constanty polling that file (eg. by ajax) to see if some new data was appended, right?

How can Crafty talk to the web page directly, saying "i have calculated another variation" or "i have decided a move" etc, then display this info on the web page and let the user give some counter move, just like in terminal. Isn't it possible to use some session / stream / listener?

I have no clue at all, can anybody point me in a right direction?

Comment: Sounds like polling would be the way to go.

Comment: Crafty looks hella cool, but it's NOT a server process - it's designed as a single-user command line app. You could, conceivably, wrap that up to power a web page, but it would be hard - every concurrent user would probably need a crafty instance running, which limits the number of concurrent users quite dramatically.

Comment: I can think off some clean solution with little modification to the taken idea. Crafty is an open source program according to its website http://www.craftychess.com/. hence you can get the source for it(ftp://ftp.cis.uab.edu/pub/hyatt) and core business logic(irrespective of language). We have business logic. Now we need to think ways to execute those. You can build new UI for it which interacts with the user and crafty logic. It is challenging but possible and it can give excellent result. What do you say?

Comment: @Dinesh, it's possible - but taking a single-user app and making it into a multi-user, stateless web application is distinctly non-trivial. It could easily consumer as much time as building the original single-user application, in my experience...

Comment: @NevilleK Yes. It is not an easy task to begin with. When there is no other way, we can do that. Nowadays we have so many chess online sites. Not worth to spend that much effort. However, we can follow this approach only if situation calls.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you make use of fifos and the `&` operator - here is why:

- You do not want to start crafty on every PHP request, you want to start it only once per game
- You don't want to have crafty end at the end of your Request
- Your move-requests will want to interact with this allready running instance.

So what I would do is something like:

- Prepare a pair of FIFOs using `mkfifo` - you can do this from PHP or from the shell
- On game start, run something like `/usr/games/crafty <stdin.fifo >stdout.fifo 2>stderr.fifo &`
- For your moves, make an AJAX PHP request write to `stdin.fifo`
- For the server moves do long polling with AJAX, on the server side opening `stdin.fifo`, then `stream_select()`